# How to convert a CCSpriteFrame to a CCTexture2D (Cocos2d)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to convert a `CCSpriteFrame` that was taken from `CCSpriteFrameCache`, and convert it into a texture that can be set on a sprite texture property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your CCSpriteFrame is named `frame` you can use:

```
[sprite setDisplayFrame:frame];
```

to [change the sprite's frame](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_sprite.html#ae41c556a12991defd766670eae6ba700) if it uses the same texture. If the texture is not the same, you must create a new sprite:

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:frame.texture];
[sprite setDisplayFrame:frame];
```

But since you already have the CCSpriteFrame you can just as well call [initWithFrame](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_sprite.html#a569cc268cf43accd6b2191452837c10c):

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has a `texture` function:

```
[[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:@"MyFrame"]texture];
```

CCSprites have a method called `setTexture` or something.