# How to convert a CCSpriteFrame to a CCTexture2D (Cocos2d)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a CCSpriteFrame to a CCTexture2D (Cocos2d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261132/how-to-convert-a-ccspriteframe-to-a-cctexture2d-cocos2d)

Is it possible to take a CCSpriteFrame that was taken from CCSpriteFrameCache, and convert it into a CCTexture2D?

i tried this:

```
-(id)initWithFile:(NSString*)filename body:(b2Body*)body  original:(BOOL)original
{
    NSAssert(filename != nil, @"Invalid filename for sprite");

    CCTexture2D *texture =  [[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:filename ]texture];

    return [self initWithTexture:texture body:body original:original];
}
```

but on the screen that shows the entire spritesheet texture not just one frame.

there is a similar question here at this link: [How to convert a CCSpriteFrame to a CCTexture2D (Cocos2d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261132/how-to-convert-a-ccspriteframe-to-a-cctexture2d-cocos2d)
but I didn't find the answers to this link helpful.

I also Tried this but I got the same results:

```
-(id)initWithFile:(CCSpriteFrame*)filename body:(b2Body*)body  original:(BOOL)original
{
   NSAssert(filename != nil, @"Invalid filename for sprite");

   CCSprite * sprite_ = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:filename];
   CCTexture2D *texture =  [sprite_ texture];
   return [self initWithTexture:texture body:body original:original];

}
```

Comment: not a duplicate. I need to convert a CCSpriteFrame to a CCTexture2D, not set it up to be used by CCSprite. I am trying to do so using this line 'CCTexture2D *texture =  [[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:filename ]texture];' but it's returning the entire spritesheet png not just a single frame.

Comment: Technically it is the same question, but their answer may not be the one that you want. You should include a reference to this in your question so that it's not marked as a duplicate and so that you can be given a correct solution!

Comment: okay I will, but by any chance do you know how I can fix my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm not very proficient in cocos2d.

Comment: Davie Montes, `spriteFrame` has property `texture`. You can't manipulate with (and even access) texture image data.

Comment: @brigadir: So what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: Tell us *why* you want to do this. There's a good chance that what you think you have to do, is not necessarily what will get you closer to the goal. There may be other, possibly better solutions. Anyhow, in principle you could use the spriteframe rect to copy part of the texture into a buffer and create a new texture (or UIImage and then a texture) from that buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
-(void) addSpriteFramesWithFile:(NSString*)plist textureFile:(NSString*)textureFileName
```

and after that:

```
CCTexture2D *cachedTexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:textureFileName];
```

?

Comment: no I haven't tried that but I will thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me (cocos2d 2.0)

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"walk_cpu_fighter_asleep.plist"];
CCSpriteFrame *fr = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"walk_cpu_fighter_asleep0001.png"];
CCSprite *spr = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:fr];

CGPoint p = [[GEPlayGrid sharedPlayGrid] positionForTileAtX:1 andY:1];

spr.position = p;
[[GameEngine sharedGameEngine].mapProvider.mapUnitsLayer addChild:spr];
```

the spriteWithSpriteFrame constructor crops properly, according to the crop spec contained in the sprite frame. Is a texture absolutely required, can you work with CCSprites ? It is hard to guess what a **self** is in your code and what it extends :) ... but maybe you may want to initWithSpriteFrame:body:original.

Comment: well what I am ultimately trying to accomplish is using PRKit :( https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fasinesio%2Fcocos2d-PRKit&ei=I5GAUNfBBsmCqgGAo4HQCw&usg=AFQjCNH6QiBkUe4eSJ4UMLD6WG8gFn-1qA) with batchnodes. It originally is set up to take a CCTexture2D

Comment: It originally is set up to take a CCTexture2D, I want to convert it to support batchnodes.